# Какое событие происходит при долгом нажатии на кружок на андроид?

Tags: android, android-intent

При нажатии и удержании сенсорной кнопки с кружком на андроиде вызывается поиск. Я хочу написать свою программу и запускать её по этому действию. Подскажите, в какую сторону вообще копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Попробуйте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21870309/3212712) заставить свою активити реагировать на соответствующий системный `Intent` путём добавления фильтра в тег активити в манифесте. После этого активити будет в числе приложений для выбора реакции на долгое нажатие. Судя по информации из ссылки в начале ответа работает с ***API Level 16***:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает.

Comment: @64-coreCPU, вот ещё один ответ с тем же самым решением: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14235060/3212712. Наверное вы что-то не так делаете. Приложение надо хотя бы раз запустить, для регистрации фильтра интентов. Так же, возможно, надо убрать гугл из действий по умолчанию для этого интента через настройки приложения гугла. Также попробуйте другой девайс - может у вас какая-то прошивка особенная

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Settings > apps > setting icon > default apps > Assist & voice input > assist app в Android M так можно поставить свое приложение

Comment: Помошни к - это не то. Браузеры долбавляют свой поиск как-то по другому. Помошни стоит "Нет", а поиск работает всё равно. В манифесте прописано следующее:

Comment: <activity
            android:label="tst"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:name=".test_activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: А всё равно активити не запускается. Программу переустанавливал и запускал. Но всё равно результата нет.

Comment: @64-coreCPU я такого ни разу не делал, но если кинете ссылку на приложение с функционалом, который вас интересует, я могу подглядеть как это у них реализовано - достаточно простого apk